# Anyone can provide simple MATLAB routine of Kernel Density Estimation?

Tags: matlab, statistics, estimation

I am trying to learn the kernel density estimation from the basic. Anyone have the simple routine for 1d KDE would be great helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the statistics toolbox in MATLAB, you can use the [`ksdensity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ksdensity.html) to estimate pdf/cdf using kernel smoothing. Here's an example

```
data=[randn(2000,1);4+randn(2000,1)];%# create a bimodal Gaussian distribution
x=linspace(-4,8,1e4);%# need to evaluate density at these points

pF=ksdensity(data,x,'function','pdf');%# evaluate the pdf of the data points
```

If you plot it, it should look like this

[image]

You can also get the cumulative distribution or the inverse cumulative or change the kernel that is used. You can look up the list of options from the link provided. This should help you get started :)